# Troubleshooting Windows Authentication problems (no challenge) in IIS 7.5?

Tags: security, iis, authentication, iis-7.5, http-authentication

I know that there are thousands of reports of people having trouble getting Integrated Windows Authentication to work with IIS, but they all seem to lead to web pages that don't apply or solutions that I've already tried. I've deployed dozens of sites like this before, so either there's something bizarre going on with the server/configuration, or I've been looking at this too long and not seeing the obvious.

Simply put, everything works perfectly on my local machine, but falls apart on the production server, which as far as I can tell has the *exact same configuration*.

On the local machine:

- The machine is running Windows 7 Ultimate, Service Pack 1, IIS 7.5.
- The site has been tested successfully, using both IIS and the VS Web Development Server.
- The IIS site config has all authentication methods disabled **except** Windows Authentication.
- The local machine is not on any domain.
- The Providers set up are Negotiate and NTLM (not Negotiate:Kerberos).
- Extended Protection is Off.
- All browsers tested (IE, Firefox, Chrome) show the challenge prompt and allow me to log in to the *localhost* domain with my (local) Windows account.
- All browsers tested also work using an opaque local IP address - so the browsers themselves don't seem to care whether the site appears "local" or "remote".
- I've added a display line to the web page which shows the currently-logged-in user and it shows exactly what I would expect (whichever local user I logged in with).

On the remote machine:

- The server is running Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5.
- Loading the web page results in an **immediate** 401.2 error: *You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.*  **No challenge prompt ever appears.**
- The IIS site config has all authentication methods disabled **except** Windows Authentication.
- The remote machine is not on any domain.
- The Providers set up are Negotiate and NTLM (not Negotiate:Kerberos).
- Extended Protection is Off.
- On the remote machine (remote desktop session), the same error appears in Internet Explorer regardless of whether the domain is *localhost* or the external IP address.
- If I try to view the *remote* web site from my *local* machine, the error is still 401, but a slightly different 401. No subcode, with the text: *Access is denied due to invalid credentials.*
- The *Windows Authentication* IIS role feature **is** installed.
- The *WindowsAuthentication* Module **is** added (at the Server level).
- The exact same error occurs if I turn off Windows Authentication and enable Basic Authentication.
- The site *does* load if I turn off Windows Authentication and enable Anonymous (obviously).
- I've already followed all of the troubleshooting steps on Microsoft Support: [Troubleshooting HTTP 401 errors in IIS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907273)
- I've already tried the [workaround shown on another Microsoft support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/871179) (supposedly to force NTLM as the only method).

Last but not least, I tried turning on FREB for 401.2 errors and the results don't seem to tell me anything useful, all I see is the following warning:

> MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS
>
> > ModuleName IIS Web Core
> >     Notification 2
> >     HttpStatus 401
> >     HttpReason Unauthorized
> >     HttpSubStatus 2
> >     ErrorCode 2147942405
> >     ConfigExceptionInfo
> >     Notification AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST
> >     ErrorCode Access is denied. (0x80070005)

...this seems to just be telling me what I already know (that it's simply rejecting the request instead of negotiating the credentials).

The trace does indicate that the WindowsAuthentication module is correctly loaded because there is a `NOTIFY_MODULE_START` line with `ModuleName` = `WindowsAuthentication` (and various other ASP.NET follow-up events - [un]fortunately, no interesting errors or warnings here).

Can anyone tell me what I might be missing here?

---

**Quick Update:**

I'm a little uncomfortable sending a whole Wireshark dump as it would reveal IPs, URLs and other stuff, but I did a side-by-side comparison of the HTTP responses from localhost and the remote server in Fiddler, and it seems fairly self-evident what the problem is:

**Localhost:**

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 17 Dec 2011 23:42:34 GMT
Content-Length: 6399
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

**Remote:**

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 17 Dec 2011 23:43:13 GMT
Content-Length: 1293
```

Aside from a few seemingly-inconsequential differences like cache-control, the main difference is that **the remote server is not sending the WWW-Authenticate headers back to the client.**

So, I guess that narrows the question down to: *Why is IIS not sending WWW-Authenticate headers when Windows Authentication appears to be installed, loaded, and exclusively enabled?*

Comment: Mind capturing a plaintext wireshark of the authentication attempt (change your password to something throwaway first - we don't want your real password hashes on the net)?  A 18 months or so back a Windows patch made some changes to HTTP NTLM negotiation (by the way, are the systems patched all the way up?) which blew up a vendor's app and gave me way more experience than I care to admit with analyzing negotiation conversations.

Comment: @ShaneMadden: I kind of do mind on account of all the various bits of information I'd be exposing, but I can do a Fiddler session which  should be almost the same, and then I can at least anonymize IPs and so on - and in fact I already did, the results should be pretty self-explanatory (the client is not showing the credentials prompt because the server isn't asking for any).

Comment: Oh, interesting, [somebody seems to have reported this problem on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1589202/38360) as well - no answers there, sadly.

Comment: @Aaronaught How did you get a different username here than on Cooking?  When I first saw this question, I thought it was someone spoofing you.

Comment: @Ward: Anybody can edit their username, it's part of the profile. This was my original one, only use others on the non-tech sites.

Answer (score 15):

Problem solved. I finally decided to compare the *module* list side-by-side and there actually was one missing. It turns out that there are **two** Windows Authentication modules:

[image: Module List]

On the server, the managed `WindowsAuthentication` module was there, but not the native `WindowsAuthenticationModule` highlighted above. Why it was configured that way is anyone's guess, but apparently if the native module is not loaded, the managed module will cheerfully load and silently fail.

So for any future readers who encounter this problem, make sure you have ***both modules loaded***, because IIS ***will not warn you*** if one of them is missing.

Comment: The managed WindowsAuthentication module isn't what it sounds like. It's support for Windows identities in ASP.Net, and it's always installed (when ASP.Net is installed). But the Windows Authentication *native* module is what gets installed when you tick the Windows Auth component in Server Manager, and that's what you need in order for that authentication option to become visible in the Authentication GUI.

Comment: @TristanK: In this case, that component was ticked, but the module was not installed. (The option was, however, visible in the Authentication GUI - so I'm pretty sure that screen depends on the managed module, not the native one.)

Comment: I'm thinking that it may have gotten this way due to some tampering with the config files (probably ApplicationHost.config). But I guess it doesn't matter how it got all out of whack; it did.

Comment: Well, clearly. Windows Auth doesn't not-work unless something happens to break it; in this case, while the question states the configuration is identical, that turns out to be untrue; so it didn't work the same. QED.

Comment: This missing module issue just bit me in Windows Server 2012 R2. It's incredible that there is no indication when this condition occurs. Anyway, thanks so much for this answer; I was literally tearing my hair out!

Comment: Where to see the list of both managed and native modules in IIS?

Answer (score 5):

We found this didn't necessarily fix the problem for developers working locally on ASP.NET sites running under Windows Authentication. We found a registry hack that disables the loopback check; this fixed it: -

registry key - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa

Create a DWORD with value 1 called "DisableLoopbackCheck"

You will have to reboot the machine for the setting to take effect

Comment: I found i could toggle between DisableLoopbackCheck being 1 and 0 and the change would take effect immediatly. In addition you can see Event ID 4625 in the event log Security log with message "The account failed to log on" .

Comment: Thank-you!  2 days of faffing about with IIS authentication and .Net versions only to find it's because I was using my hosts file to create a dummy DNS entry whilst testing a site migration.

Comment: it's safer to set BackConnectionHostNames instead of DisableLoopbackCheck, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/926642/error-message-when-you-try-to-access-a-server-locally-by-using-its-fqd for details.